# ArcGIS Pro: How can I add layer effects to all Values with 'Unique Value' Symbology

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, unique-value

I have a polygon feature class I want symbolized by a unique value attribute, in ArcGIS Pro.
Here is my example of this basic operation:
[image]

When I select one of these values, go to the 'More'-> 'format symbol(s)', I have the option to add a 'Donut effect' to the solid fill of my layer as shown here:
[image]

As you can see it edits the symbol for the feature I had selected.
I want to do this to ALL of the unique values of this feature class. But when I go to the 'More' -> 'Symbols' -> 'Format all symbols' for example, the option to add a layer effect is not there. Same for when I select more than one value and a time and do 'More'-> 'format symbol(s), the option to add a layer effect is not there.

Is it possible that the only solution to this is to edit each value's symbol one by one? I have hundreds in this feature class I need to edit.